# Compare Two Strings With Other Meaning

Tags: scala

I have big problem with comparing strings because of meaning in string. For examples, I have string like "Yellow" and string like "Blue". IN my application, Yellow is less than Blue. So how I model this? I tried to use enumeration like this

```
object Color extends Enumeration {
 val yellow = Value(0)
 val blue  = Value(1)
}
```

And in my function I having

```
def isBigger(color1 : String, color2 : String) = Boolean = {
???
}
```

But I am not suring how to compare them. Please some advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using a color `Map` with each color assigned a weight (in accordance with specific business logic), like below:

```
val colorMap = Map("Yellow"->1, "Red"->2, "Blue"->3).withDefaultValue(0)

def isBigger(c1: String, c2: String): Boolean = colorMap(c1) > colorMap(c2)

isBigger("Yellow", "Blue")
// res1: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert `String` to `Color` value using `withName`, and then compare them:

```
object Color extends Enumeration {
 val yellow = Value(0)
 val blue  = Value(1)
}
def isBigger(color1 : String, color2 : String) : Boolean = 
     Color.withName(color1) < Color.withName(color2)

println(isBigger("blue", "yellow"))  //false
println(isBigger("yellow", "blue"))  //true
```